# Jmeter : how to get large number of rps in jmeter

Tags: testing, jmeter, load-testing

I'm testing a web app using jmeter for load test and I getting a hard time on how can I set properly how many threads, ramp-up and loops will I use in order to get a large number of rps. Anyway, I want to check if my server can keep up to 500rps. Does anyone here can help me how can I set it properly. Thanks.

Comment: https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer

Answer (score 1):

The number of requests per unit of time is called [Throughput](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html) and mainly depends on two factors:

1. Number of active threads
2. Your application response time

The first one is obvious - more threads -> more requests per second. However JMeter will wait for response from the previous thread before starting the next request so application response time matters as well.

So the recommendations are:

1. Set number of threads in the [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) to the number of **anticipated** users of your system.
2. [Set ramp-up period accordingly to the number of threads](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-ramp-up-the-ultimate-guide) so the load will increase (and decrease) **gradually**, this way you will be able to correlate increasing/decreasing load with the changing response time and throughput
3. Instead of loops it might be a better idea to set desired test duration using Scheduler section of the Thread Group.

   [image: JMeter Ramp-uP and Duration]
4. Run your test and observe the actual throughput using i.e. [Server Hits Per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HitsPerSecond/https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HitsPerSecond/) listener or **Transactions per second** chart of the [HTML Reporting Dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html). If it matches your expectations - you are done, if not - you will need to increase the number of virtual users.

Comment: I appreciate your comment :)

this is what I did it:
https://snag.gy/7GMij4.jpg

https://snag.gy/KZIc2q.jpg

https://snag.gy/Z6EgFV.jpg

Do you think my ramp-up is correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ConcurrencyThreadGroup](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) plugin , Specifically see how to [Produce Desired RPS](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/#How-Many-Threads-I-Need-To-Produce-Desired-RPS):

> Threads pool size can be calculated like `RPS * <max response time> / 1000`. The more rate desired the more threads you will need. The more response time service have the more threads you will need.
>
> For example, if your service response time may be 2.5sec and target
> rps is 1230, you have to have 1230 * 2500 / 1000 = 3075 threads.